# Can't using built-in laptop camera when running OpenCV code on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013, webcam, video-capture

I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8&feature=iv&src_vid=bSeFrPrqZ2A&annotation_id=annotation_178711) tutorial to install OpenCV on my **Toshiba Satellite P755 laptop**. This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using namespace cv;

int main() {

    //Create matric to store image
    Mat image;
    //initialize capture

    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    //create window to show image
    namedWindow("window", 1);

    while (1){

        // copy webcam stream to image
        cap >> image;

        // print image to screen
        imshow("window", image);

        //delay 33ms
        waitKey(33);

    }
}
```

It's all running well with an external USB Logitech camera but whenever I'm trying to run it with my built-in laptop camera I get the following error.
[image: error message]

I've tried to re-install the camera drivers (even-tough the camera works perfectly fine with other applications) and I tried to change `cap.open(0);` to `cap.open(1);` (while the Logitech camera is connected) but I still get the same error. I see the blue light of the camera turns on but I don't get any live image in the camera window and instead the error message pops up. I tried to debug it and while I run it step by step (using F10) the error message does not show and I get **a single** frame from my camera in the camera window but I can't open it to be the main window but only to watch it on the background when I hover above it in the quick launch bar:

[image: single frame of the built-in camera when debugging]

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and Visual Studio 2013 12.0.21005.1 REL.

Comment: can you open the camera with VLC oder DirectShow (e.g. GraphStudio)?

Comment: Yes, I can. As I've mentioned, my webcam works perfectly fine with any other application (including VLC)

Comment: could you try VideoInput library?

Comment: or better: could you add a if(image.empty())continue; in your code before the imshow?

Comment: looks like your camera doesnt deliver images in each iteration so you have to check whether a image was generated or not.